# Проверка совпадения пароля введенного на странице с паролем в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Я захешировал пароль с помощью password_hash и отправил его в БД и как мне теперь при авторизации при вводе моего пароля получить тот же хеш, что хранится в БД?

Совпадения нахожу вот так:

`$check_user = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$password'");`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
Т.е. надо взять хеш из БД и проверить на PHP

Comment: А sql injection кто фиксить будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy правда удивительно, что в 2022 всё ещё пишут без prepare statement?)) Вот мне тоже. При том при всём что тут mysql**i**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это учебный проект, я только учусь

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров Вы учитесь на книгах 2000-го года вместо новых?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский посоветуйте современную литературу, пожалуйста

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров ну вроде все советуют php7 в подлиннике (Котеров, Симдянов). Правда уже есть php8.1, но пока 7 сойдёт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Достаём пользователя из БД **только по логину**
2. Сравниваем пароль, который ввёл пользователь и тот, что достали из бд через **[password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php)**
3. Если не совпадают - до свиданья, если совпадают - ок